# Creating permissioned networks with geth only

Tags: proof-of-authority, geth-clique, permissioned-chain

This is a question about permissioning in private network, but actually articulated in 2 subquestions.

Q1) Is it possibile to setup geth for a private ethereum PoA network with whitelist of nodes allowed to join, or this can be only done using Quorum or any other different node implementation?

Q2) If I don't want to use Quorum, what about creating permissioning by VPN so that only the nodes allowed to the VPN are visible to each other